# How to request DirectLine API from HeroCard's button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, botframework

I have an MVC project is using .NET.

There is one button in my hero card and I want to make a `POST` request to DirectLine API by clicking on that button.

```
var heroCard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HeroCard>(attachment.Content.ToString());

if (heroCard != null) {
  objchat.ChatResponse += " " +  heroCard.Title + " " + heroCard.Subtitle;

  if (heroCard.Images != null) {
    IList<CardImage> cardImages = heroCard.Images;

    foreach(var image in cardImages) {
      objchat.ChatResponse += " " + RenderImageHTML(image.Url);
    }
  }

  if (heroCard.Buttons != null) {
    IList<CardAction> cardButtons = heroCard.Buttons;

    foreach(var button in cardButtons) {
      objchat.ChatMessage = button.Title;
      objchat.ChatResponse += " " + "<input type='button' value='" + button.Title + "' >";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed code block and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the button on your Hero Card send a postback to your bot / server code, and have the request triggered when your bot handles the postback.

[You can see the documentation for postback() here.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.cardaction#postback)

Make sure your `postback()` call  sends some unique string that your bot can recognize, ideally, something a normal user would never send.

`postback(session, "thisIsMyUniquePostbackString")`

Then you can check in the dialog

```
if( session.message.text === "thisIsMyUniquePostbackString ){
    //HeroCard was tapped, send POST request...
}
```

I created a [working sample that you can check out here.](https://github.com/Fignewton5/Azure_Bot_node_Example_HeroCard_Postback_Request/blob/master/node_bot.js)

Please not that I have included the `request-promise` node module to issue the HTTP POST request, but you can use whatever method / library you prefer.

Here's a screenshot of the working sample in action:

[image]